Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown with submenu and hyperlink
In my bootstrap navbar the dropdown have submenus and the submenus also have submenus along with hyperlink.
When I am using in desktop the dropdown is showing the submenus on hover but in mobile it when the submenu is clicked then it hits the hyperlink and does not shows the other submenus. I want to have both of the feature like if submenu link is clicked then goes to the hyperlinked site and if icon is clicked then show the other submenu.


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-white navbar-static-top navbar-expand-lg header-sticky">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse"><i class="fas fa-align-left"></i></button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Navbar </a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Dropdown <i class="fas fa-chevron-down fa-xs"></i></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="example.com">Dropdown 1 <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu left-side">

                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="example2.com">Submenu 1 <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i> </a>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu  left-side">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="example3.com">Submenu 2 <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i> </a>

                      <ul class="dropdown-menu  left-side">

                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="example4.com">Submenu 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




This is probably not a difficult question, but it is quite incomprehensible. I've read it three times, and I'm still confused about which dropdown or submenu of a submenu or submenus you're talking about. Why not give each menu an unique name and then clearly refer to these names? Also, hovering never does anything for me. You should also thank isherwood for making your code executable, but I still think it doesn't quite execute the same as it does for you. Please edit your question to resolve these issues.
